# How do I sort JSONObjects in an JSONArray in Java (Server side)?

Tags: java, json

```
@GET
  @Produces("application/json")
  @Consumes("application/json")
  @Path("/getStuff/{id}")
  public String getStuff(
      @PathParam("id") String id,
      @Context HttpServletRequest request,
      @Context HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
  {
      Collection<Stuff> stuff = Manager.getStuff().values();
      JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();    
      for (Stuff i : stuff)
      {          
        jsnObjct.put("id", i.getId());
        jsnObjct.put("name", i.getName());
        jArray.add(jsnObjct);
      }
      json = jArray.toString();
      response.setContentType("text/javascript");
      response.getOutputStream().print(json);
      response.flushBuffer();  
      return null;
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you sort your Java objects before you put them in a JSON array?  And I think your loop should be `for (Stuff i : stuff)`

Comment: JSONObjects are not comparable.  So, sort by what?

Comment: @James, he can sort by whatever he wants. He can sort his `Collection<Stuff>` before he iterates over it.  He can break apart each `Stuff` into a `TreeMap` where key=`getId()` and val=`getName()`, for example, then iterate over the `TreeMap` and build his JSON array.  He could extend the `JSONObject` class and make it comparable.

Comment: @Paul, I agree.  I'm just trying to get him/her to provide more information, so we don't have to list all those possibilities.

Comment: @JamesClark, oops, sorry, I thought you were asking me (even though you didn't reference me).  Didn't mean to jump in on your quiz! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're using the net.sf.json library for this? If so, I'd try something like the following. I don't know for sure if this would work, but if it does work it will be by far the easiest approach. Unfortunately I'm not too familiar with that library so I'm not sure of the exact details (you may be able to skip the creation of a second JSONArray - not sure if add(int, Object) pushes objects down or overwrites them):

```
Object[] myArray = jArray.toArray();
myArray = Arrays.sort(myArray);
JSONArray sortedJArray = new JSONArray();
for (Object obj : myArray) {
  sortedJArray.add(obj);
}
```

Comment: Json-lib (the library you mentioned) makes it easy to work with collections and arrays ([examples](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/usage.html#arrays)):  `JSONArray jsonArray = JSONArray.fromObject( "['json','is','easy']" );`